# Find a specific string between two specific words in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, search, python-re

I want to separate the stem and options of a multiple choice question.

for example:

```
import re
newstr = "1 which season do you like best after looking at these pictures A spring B summer C autumn D winter E none"
result = re.search('1(.*)A', newstr)
print(result)
```

but the output result is not my expected result.

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 65), match='1 which season do you like best after looking at >
```

The result I hope to get is:

```
str1 = 'which season do you like best after looking at these pictures'
str2 = 'spring summer autumn winter none'
```

How can I achieve it?

thanks

Comment: `(?<=1)(.*)(?<=A)` for question

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `re.split`:

```
>>> _, str1, str2 = re.split("(?<=1)\s(.*)\s(?=A)", newstr)
>>> str2 = re.sub("[A-Z]\s", "", str2)
>>> str1
'which season do you like best after looking at these pictures'
>>> str2
'spring summer autumn winter none'
>>>
```